# How to show tocdata section author using extarticle

Tags: table-of-contents, author, journal, extsizes

When I use the `article` document class, I am able to see the author displayed on the right hand side of the table of contents.

However, when I use the `extarticle` document class, as below, with or without a font size option, the author is not displayed.

Furthermore, when I use the `partauthor` command in place of `sectionauthor`, even with the `extarticle` class it works as expected.

In all instances, the author is displayed underneath the heading in the body of the document - just not always in the table of contents.

If anybody knows of a more appropriate way to achieve this, or how to fix the problem, it'd be much appreciated.

I'm new to Latex so I may be going about it entirely the wrong way, in which case more context may be useful. In essence, I am using Latex to pull together multiple articles by different authors for a journal (hence each section having an author) and am displaying this on A4 paper in two column format (hence needing a smaller font size - 9pt works well).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[left=0.4in,right=0.4in,top=0.4in,bottom=0.8in,twocolumn]{geometry}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.4in}

\usepackage{tocdata}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{bottom=0.8in,onecolumn}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\afterpage{\aftergroup\restoregeometry}

\sectionauthor{Preface}{John}{Smith}

Hello World!

\end{document}
```

Comment: extarticle doesn't use the command patched by tocdata for the section entry. Why do you want to use this class?

Comment: cheers for getting back to me! in order to have a base font size of 9pt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like using the document class `scrartcl` enables smaller font sizes whilst also respecting sectionauthor, so I could achieve the desired behaviour.

(Although I'm not sure if this is good practice or for the right reasons, it seems to work!)